# Lowering DDR3 speed back to 1333 after enabling XMP

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bios, overclocking

I have following setup:

- GA-P55-UD3 Motherboard
- CPU i5-750 2.67Ghz

I recently bought 8GB of Kingston HyperX 1600Mhz CL9 RAM but my system showed it as running at 1333Mhz so following some internet advice I turned on XMP in BIOS. This changed RAM frequency to 1600Mhz but also caused my **CPU to overheat badly** - my PC switches itself off after about 10 minutes of use. I managed to turn off XMP in BIOS but my RAM speed stays at 1600Mhz and the overheating problem persists.  Now my question is how do I change RAM speed back?

In BIOS I can't do it directly (RAM freq setting is blue/disabled) but I can manipulate *CPU multiplier*, *system memory multiplier* (i can set 6, 8, 10 or currently - auto), *BCLK frequency* (160), *CPU clock ratio* (17x) and some voltages.

Can I change BCLK to 133 and CPU Clock ratio to 20? (I found that 20 is the default clock ratio for this CPU and that would make sense, but I know nothing about overclocking etc. so I'm really afraid of breaking something).

Comment: You can but you would still be over clocking your CPU and given your hardware that will cause it to overheat

Comment: Why would I overclock the CPU if these are the default values?

Comment: Because the settings your asking are value for the CPU not the memory alone which can't be changed with the hardware you have

Comment: I can't change memory speed directly but from what I understand Ram frequency is product of BCLK and memory multiplier - both of which I _can_ change. As I wrote below, mem frequency seems to be allright, vcore sits between 1.1-1.2v and dram voltage is around 1.5-1.6.

Comment: But when you change those values you said your CPU overheats.

Comment: It started to overheat after enabling XMP - I didn't change anything else before. Since then I've been changing things to restore them to pre-XMP state and I'm yet to see if I really succeded. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to set the ram speed and timings manually. It has been my experience that some motherboards simply don't like XMP settings and try to overclock your CPU to get the RAM to run at it's the XMP defined speed/timings.  You will need to refer to your motherboard's manual on how to set the memory speed/timings manually. You will also need to adjust your Base Clock and CPU Clock to the default settings as well if going the manual route. If you do what you proposed you should be ok because your cpu will run at 133 x 20 which will give you the stock 2.66 GHz. One other thing you need to check is the voltage the cpu is set at and make sure your using stock voltages.

Comment: I changed to 133x20 but it still overheats. Worst part is I don't know what else has changed after I flipped the XMP switch and it looks like it generally turned my PC into a berserker. I'll search my MoBo manual to see the proper voltage, but I would be the happiest if I could revert **all** the changes. I installed my OS today so I could setup setup everything from scratch painlessly if I only knew what to reset first.

Comment: Restore the defaults then....

Comment: You may have changed to 133x20 but the voltages are probably not set correctly (causing the heat issue). Did you check your timings and voltages as well for both the cpu and the memory?

Comment: Also, you can always reset your bios to get the default settings back. Once you do this save those settings and you should be running at default spec. Once you have it running at default spec use a program like cpuz to observe the default voltage and clock speed settings. You can also inspect your ram's speed/timings using cpuz.

Comment: How do I restore the defaults then? That's exactly what I would love to do! In BIOS I have: Load fail safe settings

Comment: That should do the trick, if not there is a little jumper (location can be found in the mobo's user manual) you can use to clear the CMOS.

Comment: I clicked enter by mistake: How do I restore the defaults then? That's exactly what I would love to do! In BIOS I have: Load _fail safe settings_ and _load optimized settings_ but I'm pretty sure I tried using these (my startup screen changed from terminal type which it always used to be to some gigabyte graphic one now) and the CPU still overheats very quickly. :-( Voltages seem to be in normal ranges as far as I know where to look at: vcore is 1.168v Dram voltage is 1.584v (my RAM has 1.65V in specs).

Comment: The manual for your motherboard describes how to restore the UEFI default settings

Comment: The CMOS jumper clear will reset the motherboard to factory settings.  Those voltages seem pretty normal to me. Are those voltages the same under load, such as when running applications or games?

Comment: Also, failsafe should be the default settings as well but if they arn't the CMOS jumper clear will always reset to factory spec.

Comment: Just make sure you unplug for you computer from the wall before you do a CMOS reset

Comment: Thanks a lot. I restored the factory settings, cleaned the fan to be sure and installed realtemp - it seems to be allright now. Gosh - 4 hours lost beacuse of a stupid switch. At least I learned something...

Comment: No problem, I've had my share of frustration with hardware before and wasted many hours as well. Glad I could help you restore it. You might be able to call Kingston tech support and get them to walk you through setting the memory up manually for the 1600 speed if you really want to take the time to do that. Hope you get it figured out. At least now you know how to do a CMOS reset if anything goes funky again :)

Answer (score -2):

The thing to always do is to backup the BIOS before performing ANY actions to it, then will have a safe, working one, even if performing not quite as good as we like.

Secondly, if you're going to buy a retail or OEM computer, many times online (example) if you desire the best RAM with performance timing, along with CPU & OC'ing, they can do that also. Word to the wise, be sure & purchase a SquareTrade warranty with the customized PC. There's also dedicated builders on the medium to large scale, or die-hard enthusiasts who knows what they're doing who will do the work, as long as you furnish all components, which retains your warranty rights. I still have both PSU's (we need to discuss this option & SSD's running well with 10 year warranties still in effect.

That said, you don't want to skimp on the PSU. Why is this? The PSU is the foundation of your build, catching say a 550-650 Gold model even by a reliable name such as EVGA at $75-90 (which most of mine are) would had been a great deal for up to GTX 1070 series & a Z97 system. But today, with GDDR5 RAM with GDDR6 coming, GPU's that'll blow 2015 models out of the water & don't forget the CPU & necessary cooling, as well as 5th gen multiple PCIe lanes across the board for GPU's, NVMe drives & much everything else, many will need at a minimum of 1200W Gold or Platinum series PSU (& no "house brands") to install in their otherwise $2,500 to $3,500 build. If one can afford these components, then get the best PSU possible, going over the "minimum" calculation.

As far as the mistake on the BIOS goes, one should be able to first, have a copy of their last released BIOS onhand, if there's a reset switch, follow any instructions on how to use. Be sure to be grounded to PC case & to remove & replace the coin cell battery (many uses CR2032 replacements). If the reset doesn't work, then it's time to flash your MB to the last released BIOS & it'll overwrite what's there. This is why it's best to back it up before tinkering. I've had to bail myself out 3-4 times, plus help others, it takes only a second to mess things up, but hours of work when not prepared & making random changes to BIOS based on articles. Dell, HP, Lenovo, etc, isn't going to tell us how to fix these things. Unless they are swamped with calls to the point to where they cannot service customers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).